# jQuery, adding deferred when $.when starts execute

Tags: jquery

is there a way to add another call to deferred array, when $.when starts executing already?

I have two buttons:

```
<div>
    <button id="btn1">Call 1</button>
    <button id="btn2">Call 2</button>
</div>
```

and some javascript:

```
var deferreds = [];
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    deferreds.push(call1a());
    deferreds.push(call1b());

    $.when.apply($, deferreds)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('when completed');
    });
});
```

This works fine, then is executed after call1a and call1b is completed.
Now I would like to add another ajax call, after button 1 is clicked, but before then function is finished:

```
$('#btn2').on('click', function () {
    deferreds.push(call2a());
});
```

but seems that when is not executing newly added call2a. 
How can i solve this?